# Auto generate script for CREATE TABLE including all indices, constraints, etc (not via SSMS)

Tags: t-sql, database-schema, auto-generate

I have a data anonymization process that takes a production copy of a database and turns it into an anonymized copy by UPDATE-ing some columns.

Some of the tables contain several million rows so instead of UPDATE-ing the columns, [which is very log intensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3711522/3588010), I went down the way of

```
SELECT 
  Id,
  CAST('Redacted' AS NVARCHAR(255)) [ColumnRequiringAnonymization]
INTO MyTable_New
FROM MyTable

EXEC sp_rename MyTable, MyTable_old
EXEC sp_rename MyTable_new, MyTable
DROP TABLE MyTable_old
```

The problem with this approach is that the "new" table no longer has any of the keys, indices and other dependent objects. I have figured out the keys and indices using SPs to generate the DROP and CREATE scripts. The SPs are based on manually written SQL as can be seen e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089812/3588010).

The next problem is that we have a schemabound view on top of this table, which has indices and a full-text index on its own. The number of SPs to generate scripts is growing and I am sure there will be mistakes.

Is there a way to completely script a table/view by using SQL commands only? ie. just like SSMS does when you click "Script table as - CREATE to" but within a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the database, select Tasks; there is Generate Scripts there. Just follow prompts or Google for additional information. [image]

Comment: The question is in context WITHOUT SSMS.

Comment: yeah, though further explanation suggests that you are using ssms. Unfortunately there is no other way.