# Copy indexes from a "parent" SQL Server database to a subset of the tables

Tags: sql-server

We have a customer that uses a 3rd party system running on SQL Server 2014. I downloaded a copy of the underlying database in .bak format from the 3rd party, which has about 1500 tables and no data. The customer uses a cut-down version of this schema with about 150 of the tables, deleting the ones they don't use.

Somehow they also managed to delete all the indexes... *sigh*. They have sent me a .bak to do some reporting queries on, but the performance is making me pull out my hair.

I would like to copy the indexes (and pkeys) from the original "pattern" database to the customer's copy. I have seen an excellent solution on how [to do this with two identical DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089700/generate-script-of-all-the-indexes-in-a-database)s, but using these leaves me with 1400 names that don't exist, and this causes problems in MSSQLAdmin. Can anyone offer a modification that does not assume the "child" DB has every table and only CREATEs on those that exist?

Comment: The easiest solution might be to download a comparison tool, like ApexSQL, and sync them that way. It appears that Apex's SQL Code Compare is free: https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-compare.aspx

Comment: Seems quite easy to adjust the code in the linked question to filter out everything not belonging to a list of tables

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using the accepted answer of [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089700/generate-script-of-all-the-indexes-in-a-database) you have mentioned :

```
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IXSQL NVARCHAR(4000) SET @IXSQL = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @IxTable + ''') IS NOT NULL BEGIN ' --create index if table exists

    SET @IXSQL = @IXSQL + 'CREATE '
    ..............
    
    SET @IXSQL = @IXSQL + ') END'
    -- Print out the CREATE statement for the index
    .................
```