# Is there a way to include auto created indexes when copying a db using the New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy command?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

It seems that `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy` skips over auto created indexes. Is there a way to include them?

Comment: I did not find a way to include auto created indexes with the `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy` command. Instead I scripted them from the original db and ran them in the copy using [such a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21940525/7718171).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Transact SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_copy   
AS COPY OF ozabzw7545.db_original ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P2' );
```

You can use Visual Studio as explained [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-compare-two-sql-databases-from-visual-studio/) to compare the schemas of both database, the original database and the newly created database.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/151239/schema-compare-does-not-take-into-account-auto-cre) thread, Visual Studio Schema Compare does not take auto generated indexes into account

Comment: Use the free trial of these tools: https://www.xsql.com/products/sql-server-schema-compare  / https://www.apexsql.com/products/sql-tools-bundle-compare/